# Change the name and surname with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

this is xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- Yavuz  -->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="books.xsl"?>
<catalog>
      <book id="bk101">
       <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
       <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
       <genre>Computer</genre>
       <price>44.95</price>
       <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      </book>
</catalog>
```

I want the author to look like this.

> The newest book is XML Developer's Guide published on 2000-10-01 and the author of this book is Matthew Gambardella.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the XSLT below to get the output text.

```
<xsl:template match="book">
    <xsl:text>The newest book is </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
    <xsl:text> published on </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="publish_date" />
    <xsl:text> and the author of this book is </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(normalize-space(substring-after(author, ',')),' ', substring-before(author, ','))" />
</xsl:template>
```